# how to resolve this xml shape tag error in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/list_row_start_color"
        android:endColor="@color/list_row_end_color"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Here is showing the error and says Element shape must be declared on shape tag please help and also showing same on select tag so what would be the solution for this

Comment: Clean your project and then rebuild it.

Comment: Error:Error: Unsupported type 'gradient'    show in catlog

Comment: @MianHassan Edit your post, add in the logs for the error.